# Throwing an exception makes error of unhandled exception

Tags: java, spring

I created an exception :

```
public class PkDeleteException extends java.lang.Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PkDeleteException(String msg) {

        super(msg);

    }

}
```

Now I threw it in the catch block of some code :

```
import com.ambre.pta.utils.PkDeleteException;

public class AdminRole {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDao;

    public void del(@RequestParam String id) {

        try {

            roleDao.delete(id);

        } catch (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException e) {

            Role role = roleDao.get(id);

            String errMsg = env.getProperty("admin.list.profils.err.suppr");

            errMsg = errMsg.replace("%s", role.getRole_lib());

            throw new PkDeleteException(errMsg);

        }

    }

}
```

But I got an error `Unhandled exception type PkDeleteException` !

There are suggested solutions proposed by Eclipse but I do not want to follow them ! So why is there this error ?

Comment: Just read about checked vs. unchecked exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: you got to declare in your method that you may throw an exception from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general or for most of the scenarios, you never create a custom exception by extending `java.lang.Exception` class directly, rather you need to extend `java.lang.RuntimeException` class (or it's subtypes, which is even more preferable).

As your current `PkDeleteException` is checked Exception, you need to declare that in your method signature using throws clause (**option-2, not preferable**) or the best practice is to convert it into unchecked Exception (**option-1**) like below:

**Option(1) - Use unchecked Exception (Preferable):**

```
public class PkDeleteException extends RuntimeExcetion {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PkDeleteException(String msg) {

        super(msg);

    }

}
```

**Option(2): Change your method signature**

from

`public void del(@RequestParam String id)`

to

`public void del(@RequestParam String id) throws PkDeleteException`

I suggest you to have a look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Answer (score -1):

Your del method should throw PkDeleteException.
Your method should be like follow

```
public void del(@RequestParam String id) throws PkDeleteException  {

    try {

        roleDao.delete(id);

    } catch (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException e) {

        Role role = roleDao.get(id);

        String errMsg = env.getProperty("admin.list.profils.err.suppr");

        errMsg = errMsg.replace("%s", role.getRole_lib());

        throw new PkDeleteException(errMsg);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain the crucial part: the `throws` declaration on the method